# Facing data loss issue while using jdbc source connector in kafka-connect

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-redshift, apache-kafka-connect

for last 5 months we are using Apache kafka with JDBC source connector for pulling our data from the Redshift database.

But now we are facing some severe data loss issue like out of 25M records we get only 9M records.

while checking the connect log we observed some thing like data was flushed

Below is the log which we get in connect.log

```
                [2021-04-28 15:34:39,485] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=SAMPLE-CONNECTOR-0} flushing 915 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:495)
                Line 24956: [2021-04-28 15:34:39,535] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=SAMPLE-CONNECTOR-0} Finished commitOffsets successfully in 50 ms (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:574)
                Line 24983: [2021-04-28 15:35:29,535] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=SAMPLE-CONNECTOR-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:478)
                Line 24984: [2021-04-28 15:35:29,536] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=SAMPLE-CONNECTOR-0} flushing 1160 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:495)
                Line 24985: [2021-04-28 15:35:29,613] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=SAMPLE-CONNECTOR-0} Finished commitOffsets successfully in 77 ms (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:574)
                Line 25012: [2021-04-28 15:36:19,613] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=SAMPLE-CONNECTOR-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:478)
                Line 25013: [2021-04-28 15:36:19,613] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=SAMPLE-CONNECTOR-0} flushing 1280 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:495)
                Line 25014: [2021-04-28 15:36:19,679] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=SAMPLE-CONNECTOR-0} Finished commitOffsets successfully in 66 ms (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:574)
                Line 25041: [2021-04-28 15:37:09,680] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=SAMPLE-CONNECTOR-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:478)
                Line 25042: [2021-04-28 15:37:09,680] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=SAMPLE-CONNECTOR-0} flushing 1628 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:495)
                Line 25043: [2021-04-28 15:37:09,781] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=SAMPLE-CONNECTOR-0} Finished commitOffsets successfully in 101 ms (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:574)
                Line 25070: [2021-04-28 15:37:59,782] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=SAMPLE-CONNECTOR-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:478)
                Line 25071: [2021-04-28 15:37:59,782] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=SAMPLE-CONNECTOR-0} flushing 29 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:495)
                Line 25072: [2021-04-28 15:37:59,
```

in this log some amount of data is continuously flushed out regularly so we thought this maybe the issue?

Did anyone faced the same issue before?

Anyone knows how to overcome this issue or what is the root cause of this issue?

Comment: Polling intervals, by design, don't capture all records. CDC would be the alternative

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer for the reply but in our connector we are using the below to achieve the same cdc behaviour  "mode": "timestamp+incrementing",
        "incrementing.column.name": "memberkey",
        "timestamp.column.name": "sourcedatachangecapturedatetime",

Comment: That's not quite the same thing. For example, with incrementing mode, if you have data updated at a timestamp older than what's already been read, you'll miss that event